# Accessing validation context in a callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm refactoring an old (and massy) Rails app and I'm wondering if it's possible to access an ActiveRecord `context` in a `validation callback`.

The current code looks like

```rb
class Operation < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :requires_update

  after_validation :update_status
  ...

  def update_status
   case status
   when 1
     ...
   when 10
    if requires_update
      status = 11
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

```rb
class OperationsController < ApplicationController
  def mark_as_complete
    ...
    if @operation.update(operation_params)
     ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

```
<%= form_for @operation, url: mark_as_complete_operation_path(@operation) do |form| %>
  <%= hidden_field :operation, :requires_update, value: "1" %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

What I'd like to do is:

1- Removing the `hidden_field`in the form (which is the only value the form posts to the controller).

2- Saving the `operation` within a specific context.

```rb
def mark_as_complete
    ...
    if @operation.save(context: :completed)
     ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
  ...
```

3- Accessing the context in the `update_status` method.

```rb
def update_status
  ...
   when 10
    if CONTEXT == :completed # What should go here?
      status = 11
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

```rb
  if @operation.save(context: :completed)
```

validates `operation` in the `completed` context before saving it. That means that you can call a validation on that context. I don't find any docs saying you can use context in the way you want to use it in an `after_validation` callback.